# Pluggable blogging for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

I am developing an app, and would like to enable blogging on it. I want the users of the site to be able to write blogs, and other users to comment on them. So far I have seen governor gem, but its not Rails 3.1 complaint.

Any suggestions?

Comment: was this problem solved ? i am facing a similar situation. the governor gem does not seem to be updated for more than a year now.

Comment: I ended up creating by own blogging system. Its not hard - Blog resource, controller, and you can use Rich Text editor or markdown editor for the view.